# I am trying to scrape Feature Image using scrapy in python but its giving result " data:image/svg+xml; .... " instead of Image src

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape Feature Image using scrapy in python but its giving result " data:image/svg+xml; .... " instead of Image src can any one help me to fix this and explain me why I am getting this `"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20600%20400'%2F%3E"` instead of image src.

Here is my Code.
class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "cruiseradio"

```
def start_requests(self):
    url = input("Enter the article url: ")
    
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    try:
        Feature_Image = [i.strip() for i in response.css('img[class*="wp-image-150660 sp-no-webp"] ::attr(src)').getall()][0]
    except IndexError:
        Author = "NULL"
    yield{
        'Feature_Image': Feature_Image,
    }
```

Here is URL of the site. https://cruiseradio.net/new-expedition-ship-delivered-atlas-ocean-voyages/

Comment: Was there something I didn't fully address in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that particular attribute is filled dynamically.  Use the `data-origin-src` attribute instead.

```
Feature_Image = [i.strip() for i in response.css('img[class*="wp-image-150660 sp-no-webp"] ::attr(data-origin-src)').getall()][0]
```

Result:

```
{'Feature_Image': 'https://cdn.cruiseradio.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Atlas_Ocean_Voyages-1030x687.jpeg'}
```